# how can I change the name in Gradle scripts , it says nestoruk_47554 but i need to change it with mine

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiY5O.png) How can I change the name in Gradle scripts

Comment: Please if possible, paste code here not image

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you wanna change names of minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, versionName, This is impossible because these names are defined in android-studio and assign the structure of your project, so No you can't change them.
in dependencies you can add a line or few lines that adds some features to your project.